# Valet with Laravel - Vue is not fully working with it

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, laravel-valet

I have set up my whole project and started valet.

In my view at the bottom I import the JS file and use mix for it to reload:

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

The issue comes into play when I try to bind anything, it just does not reflect on valet. It works with a regular artisan serve but I need valet.

Example:

```
<template>
   <div>
     <input v-model="text" />

   <p>{{ text }}</p>
   </div>


</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            text: '',
        }
    },
</script>
```

The text will not appear or update with Valet. Is it something I am doing wrong? I have no errors in the console. I am running `npm run watch` and it builds successfully each time.

Comment: Did you test if it's the cache giving you an older version of your script? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting

Comment: @Anders I'll have to test this. Hope this is it - everything looks like its working but this.